# Spark configuration issue

Tags: apache-spark, memory

I have 10 EC2 instances of M5.2xlarge (CPU: 8, Memory: 32g). I am trying to run a Spark job with 70000 input files having overall size of 30 Mb. Initially my jobs were failing because of the error shown below:

```
Total size of serialized results of 37 tasks (1036.0 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

So I added the parameter `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to 4 Gb. Now my executor pods are failing because of:

```
Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
```

Below are my overall configurations. I think there's some issue in the executor memory. What should be the right configuration?

```
EXECUTOR_MEMORY=22g
EXECUTOR_CORES=6
NUM_EXECUTORS=5
DRIVER_MEMORY=22g
MAX_RESULT_SIZE=4g
```

Comment: `set by SparkConf: conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "600s")
set by spark-defaults.conf: spark.network.timeout 600s
set when calling spark-submit: --conf spark.network.timeout=600s`

Answer (score 0):

10 instances of M5.2xlarge is an overshooting for an overall data volume of 30MB. Probably you meant 30MB on average which is 70,000 x 30MB = 2.1TB, in this case the dimensioning is reasonable.

My first guest would be that the workers are too busy to send the heartbeat. Probably they are hung up on running the garbage collector which usually goes back to non optimal spark usage. Although you can try to increase the memory on the executors (you have still 10gigs to go), but a better approach would be to restructure your processing code to not to use that much memory if it's possible.